# Is there a read write lock with listeners for java?

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8

Is there a java library that implements something that behaves like a `ReadWriteLock` but uses listeners or CompletableFuture/CompletionStage instead of blocking?

Ideally I'd like to write:

```
lock = ...

CompletionStage stage = lock.lockRead();
stage.thenAccept(r -> { doSomething(); r.release(); });
```

And also important:

```
CompletionStage stage = lock.tryLockWrite(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
stage.handle(callback);
```

---

I'm looking to know if something like this exists and if it does *how is it called*.

I'm not looking to implement this myself, but rather use a library to simplify some framework code.

Comment: This is `java-8` with lambdas, right?

Comment: Right, but I'm not asking for lambdas.  However CompletionStage is available only in java-8

Comment: What would the semantics of that ReadWriteLock with CompletableFuture be? A CompletableFutures handler is invoked by another thread, at an unspecified time in the future. Do you mean to extend the read lock until that handler completes in another thread, to reacquire the lock for the completion, or not have any lock during completion?

Comment: ... and wait, you want a non-blocking lock? By definition, acquiring a lock must block until it is available, so can't be non-blocking.

Comment: About "Lock". Yeh. Makes sense, that's why I've written "something that behaves like", I'm not sure if the the "Lock" name fits there.

However the MT semantics seems clear, at least to me. You ask for the lock (access to a resource). You get it. You have to release it. The only thing is that it can happen in one or more threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think writing it yourself shouldn't be hard enough. Chances are it would take less time than looking for a library. It's pretty simple overall:

```
static const int STATE_UNLOCKED = 0;
static const int STATE_READING = 1;
static const int STATE_WRITING = 2;
int state = STATE_UNLOCKED;
int readers = 0;
Queue<CompletableFuture<Void>> queueWriters = new LinkedList<CompletableFuture<Void>>();
Queue<CompletableFuture<Void>> queueReaders = new LinkedList<CompletableFuture<Void>>();

public synchronized CompletionStage<Void> lockWriter() {
    CompletableFuture<Void> l = new CompletableFuture<Void>();
    if (state == STATE_UNLOCKED) {
        state = STATE_WRITING;
        l.complete(null);
        return l;
    }
    queueWriters.offer(l);
    return l;
}

public synchronized CompletionStage<Void> lockReader() {
    CompletableFuture<Void> l = new CompletableFuture<Void>();
    if (state != STATE_WRITING) {
        state = STATE_READING;
        readers++;
        l.complete(null);
        return l;
    }
    queueReaders.offer(l);
    return l;
}

public void unlock() {
    CompletableFuture<Void> l = null;
    synchronized(this) {
        if (state == STATE_READING) {
            readers--;
            if (readers > 0) {
                return;
            }
        }
        l = queueReaders.poll();
        if (l != null) {
            state = STATE_READING;
            readers++;
        }
        else {
            l = queueWriters.poll();
            if (l != null) {
                state = STATE_WRITING;
            }
            else {
                state = STATE_UNLOCKED;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    l.complete(null);
    while (true) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (state != STATE_READING) {
                return;
            }
            l = queueReaders.poll();
            if (l == null) {
                return;
            }
            readers++;
        }
        l.complete(null);
    }
}
```

Adding timed locking (By using some sort of "expiring queue" or writer-starvation prevention (By preventing additional readers from being executed if `queueWriters` is not empty) to the above shouldn't be that much more difficult either.

Comment: So, I've solved my problem with something like this. However I'm looking for a library with ["Doug Lea"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doug_Lea) level of quality.

Comment: When it comes to promises/async, there aren't much better solutions than using queues. It's not like you can spin-lock without having an equivalent number of threads running. If you search hard enough, you'll probably find something pre-packaged, but not necessarily "better". One thing that could be improved in my implementation is the call to "complete" in "lockReader" and "lockWriter" happening inside the synchronized block. Alternately, if you are guaranteed single-threaded operation (Event loop?), you can skip synchronization entirely.